# Press and hold for accented character menu disables letter input in Mojave

Tags: mojave, input-source, text-input

After upgrade to Mojave, a long press of any letter does not bring up the accented character menu. Instead it disables all letters from being inputted in applications (Messages, Safari, Skype, TextEdit, Chrome and others).

Special keys like `backspace` and `return` still work.

If I execute `defaults write NSGlobalDomain ApplePressAndHoldEnabled -bool false`, press and hold repeats the letter, and input is not disabled.

If I change it back to `true`, input gets disabled after a press and hold.

Comment: Are you using the US input source or another one?

Comment: Do you have this problem in Pages, Mail, Safari, Notes, Message as well?

Comment: Yes for Notes, Safari and Messages. The input source is Canadian English.

Comment: Can you try another keyboard?  That would indicate whether your c key is bad somehow.

Comment: Not seeing behavior on a 2017 MBP/touchbar. Long pressing characters (including C) works as expected. çćč... what hardware are you running?

Comment: @TomGewecke It's the same for any key. The keyboard worked fine before Mojave.

Comment: @dr.nixon 2017 27 iMac.

Comment: Any anti virus stuff installed?  Same problem if you create a new user acct and long into that?

Comment: @TomGewecke Another user account which existed before upgrade to Mojave continues to function as expected, wit accented character menu correctly shown.

Comment: Sounds like some anti virus or other 3rd party app interfering with things in your main account.

Comment: I had a weird, unreproducible issue with my own account years ago - other accounts on same computer didn't show odd behavior, only mine - resolved by deleting and rebuilding the account. Sometimes old prefs or settings make a mess. It's the nuclear option but it should fix your issue...?

Comment: @dr.nixon The issue seems to have resolved by itself after a couple of days. I still have no clue why it would happen.